# Strings.xml file and valus.xml file error

Tags: android-studio

ERROR:C:\Users\appdhaka\WhatsUp\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:121: AAPT: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka com.neatroots.whatsup:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWB4S.png)